# File download IE

Tags: security, internet-explorer, https, download

I have an app that uses an iframe with https that returns a file. It's working in every browser but not in IE.

Did someone had the same issue and has a solution that allows to download the file without touching the IE security settings

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How *exactly* is it "not working" in IE? What error(s) you get, if any? What IE versions? What headers are you sending with the download? (blind guess: check the caching headers: no-cache+HTTPS=IE download error)

Comment: You may get a more useful reply if you provide your download code and a dump of the HTTP response headers it generates. Please update your answer with these items.